# PHP Base64_decode

Tags: php, base64

I am using the following code to encode a URL for basic hiding of the URL

```
/lbs_map.php?msisdn=27827910118
```

This is what I do not want my clients to see. I have coded it the following way

```
<a href="lbs_map.php?msisdn=<?php echo base64_encode ("27".substr($rows['member_msisdn'],  
1)); ?>
```

This is my output now:

```
/lbs_map.php?msisdn=Mjc4Mjc5MTAxMTk=
```

I am using this to try and decode the string:

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

But it is not working at all to decode it and give me the required info i want. I need help on the decoding of the string

The encode string must work with the code string as the code string varies and is never the same

Comment: http://www.e-track.co.za/lbs_map.php?msisdn=Mjc4Mjc5MTAxMTk= in the URL and on the Screen

This is an encoded string

Comment: It works fine. It says "This is an encoded string". Which is exactly what `$str` is holding.

Comment: you cannot copy code verbatim from the documentation site and expect it to work in your situation. As I said in your past question, you **really** need to get the basics of programming and PHP before you can continue.

Comment: The number it is coding is not what it is bringing out again $str should be the number i coded and that number varies

Comment: All I am trying to do is hide the msisdn output on the new PHP page basically

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing base64 encoded data via the url, you need to `urlencode()` it first as `=` is a reserved character in urls.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to `urlencode()` the `msisdn` parameter.
2. Also keep in mind that `base64` is not the way to go if you want to hide something from your users as it's not an encryption function and can be easily decoded.